# Footer won't clear float content

Tags: css-float, footer, multiple-columns

Having issues with my footer clearing these columns.

You can view the source code here: http://gc200298785.computerstudi.es/atwopodiatry/default.php?id=3

Thanks in advance!
Kayley

Answer (score 0):

remove the   `position: absolute;` on your footer